# Reliably calculate accurate device resolution

Tags: javascript, css, screen-resolution, devicepixelratio

Assuming window.devicePixelRatio and device-width are set by display manufacturers and could potentially return incorrect values, are there any other reliable ways to accurately calculate the resolution of the physical pixels on a display?

I'll use my phone (Samsung Galaxy S9+) as an example, in portrait it has:

- a screen resolution of: **1,440 × 2,960**
- a device-width of: **412**
- a devicePixelRatio of **3.5**

The width of the device in physical pixels can be calculated by: `device-width * devicePixelRatio`

**412 * 3.5 ≠ 1440**

I'm willing to believe any one of those values is wrong. Perhaps the width in physical pixels really is **1442**, or maybe the device-width is actually **411.42857142857142857142857142857**, or the devicePixelRatio is **3.4951456310679611650485436893204**‬.

Either way something's not right, and I'm left wondering how often this inaccuracy occurs and if there's any way to work around the issue without having to fallback on a database of manually updated known device resolutions.